# eclipselink dynamic table at runtime

Tags: java, eclipselink

Using eclipselink 2.0 how is it possible to generate more than one table per mapped entity?
That is, having a POJO to map a Client and then for each new Client to create a set of tables called X_clientId, Y_clientId, Z_clientId (with X, Y, Z being mapped entities). And the tables X, Y, Z should have the same structure for each client.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand, perhaps clarify.  Have you considered inheritance?  You could have X, Y, Z subclasses of Client.

You may also look into EclipseLink multi-tenant support.